# Fedora 28 USB phone mount troubles

Tags: fedora, usb, mtp

Since I upgraded Fedora to version 28 I have problems seeing from the terminal at which point my phone is mounted.. I can see it through the GUI only, and when I take a look its path from the file manager I view this `mtp://%5Busb%3A002,009%5D/`.

With `lsusb` command I can see it, but nothing about its mount point using `lsblk` command

```
# dmesg | tail
[ 1737.401875] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 1737.401877] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 1754.111497] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1759.514569] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 1759.594277] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0c02, bcdDevice= 2.16
[ 1759.594283] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1759.594287] usb 2-1.2: Product: MT65xx Android Phone
[ 1759.594290] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 1759.594294] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 2626.001808] perf: interrupt took too long (4953 > 4952), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40000
```

Answer (score 0):

`mtp://` devices aren't typically mounted at the top level of directories that `lsblk` would reveal. They're often times nested under a path such as `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/`, where `$UID` would be your username's userid when expanded. You can find this out via the `id` command:

```
$ id
uid=1000(manny) gid=1000(manny) groups=1000(manny),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

**NOTE:** Here my `$UID` would be 1000.

I'd investigate this directory to start from your terminal, `find /run/user -type d` and see if it's located under there.

#### References

- [Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem)

Comment: Hi slm, thank you for reply me. I had tried to go at /run/user/1000/gvfs/ directory, but with root permissions the /gvfs directory is hidden... So using the command CD normally only I goal. Thanks for your help now I understand. Have a nice day !

Comment: @RinoRemix - if this has resolved your issue please mark it as the accepted answer so that other's know your issue's been resolved.